# React Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition in UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In React App, I am triggering API request / data load in useEffect() in the screen which shows loading indicator.

```
    export default function LoadingScreen({ onLoaded}: {
onLoaded: (result: Result) => void;
}) {

useEffect(() => {
    const getProductByCode = async () => {
    const result = await getProduct();
    onLoaded(result)
    };

    getProductByCode().catch(console.error);
});

return (…)
```

And when data is loaded, trying to switch the state here:

```
<LoadingScreen  onLoaded={(result) => dispatch({ type: 'success', result })} />
```

It kind of works but I get this warning and I think it is not ok still

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Can someone give me a bit more explanation on what is happening here (why warning is coming)? I thought useEffect() is called after rendering is done so invoking async dispatch after server response should be very much ok, no?

P.S. Added call stack. The line mentioned is  const history = useHistory(); which does not make sense to me.

```
index-057ed940.js:1246 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
at App (https://localhost:8080/dist/App.js:69:19)
at Router (https://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-router-dom.js:1683:30)
at BrowserRouter (https://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-router-dom.js:2409:35)
at default
at InnerThemeProvider (https://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/@material-ui/core.js:8806:17)
at ThemeProvider$1 (https://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/@material-ui/core.js:4006:5)
at ThemeProvider (https://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/@material-ui/core.js:8826:5)
```

Comment: you are calling something like setState in render

Comment: you need to add a dependency list in useEffect. If you want to call it only on the first render add an empty dependency list []